# Selecting a single value field from CSV file

Tags: ruby, csv

I want to extract a specific value from a single field in my CSV file, but any research I have done points towards using hashes to extract whole columns of data rather than value.

```
Name,Times arrived,Total $ spent,Food feedback
Dan,34,2548,Lovin it!
Maria,55,5054,"Good, delicious food"
Carlos,22,4352,"I am ""pleased"", but could be better"
Stephany,34,6542,I want bigger steaks!!!!!
```

For example, I wish to extract the values 2548 and 4352 to add and merge into a total for a new row.

I have used:

```
CSV.foreach("file.csv") { |row| col_data_new << row[5] }
```

to extract values from a column into an array but this time I just want one value.

Comment: You are looking for [`CSV::filter`](http://www.ruby-doc.org/stdlib-2.2.0/libdoc/csv/rdoc/CSV.html#method-c-filter).

Comment: Can you show expected output..? It will help us to give you the answer fast?

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow. It's not necessary to tell us you're new and/or learning. We are all learning, even those of us who have programmed for ages. Just ask well thought-out questions, try to solve the problem beforehand and search for solutions before asking, and show us what you tried, and we'll be happy to help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, hashes are the way to go:

```
require 'csv'

data = 'Name,Times arrived,Total $ spent,Food feedback
Dan,34,2548,Lovin it!
Maria,55,5054,"Good, delicious food"
Carlos,22,4352,"I am ""pleased"", but could be better"
Stephany,34,6542,I want bigger steaks!!!!!
'

CSV.parse(data, headers: :first_row).map{ |row| row["Total $ spent"] }
# => ["2548", "5054", "4352", "6542"]
```

Pretend that

```
CSV.parse(data, headers: :first_row)
```

is really

```
CSV.foreach('some/file.csv', headers: :first_row)
```

and the data is really in a file.

The reason you want to use `headers: :first_row` is that tells CSV to gobble up the first line. Then it'll return a hash for each record, using the associated header field for the keys, making it easier to retrieve specific fields by name.

From [the documentation](http://www.ruby-doc.org/stdlib-2.2.0/libdoc/csv/rdoc/CSV.html#method-c-new):

```
:headers
```

> If set to :first_row or true, the initial row of the CSV file will be treated as a row of headers.

Alternate ways of doing this are:

```
spent = CSV.parse(data).map{ |row| row[2] }
spent.shift

spent
# => ["2548", "5054", "4352", "6542"]
```

`spent.shift` drops the first element from the array, which was the header field for that column, leaving the array containing only values.

Or:

```
spent = []
skip_headers = true
CSV.parse(data).each do |row| 

  if skip_headers
    skip_headers = false
    next
  end

  spent << row[2]
end

spent
# => ["2548", "5054", "4352", "6542"]
```

Similar to the [`shift`](http://www.ruby-doc.org/core-2.2.0/Array.html#method-i-shift) statement above, the `next` is telling Ruby to skip to the next iteration of the loop and not process the rest of the instructions in the block, which results in the header record being skipped in the final output.

Once you have the values from the fields you want you can selectively extract specific ones. If you want the values "2548" and "4352", you have to have a way of determining which rows those are in. Using arrays (the non-header method) makes it more awkward to do, so I'd do it using hashes again:

```
spent = CSV.parse(data, headers: :first_row).each_with_object([]) do |row, ary| 
  case row['Name']
  when 'Dan', 'Carlos'
    ary << row['Total $ spent']
  end
end

spent
# => ["2548", "4352"]
```

Notice that it's very clear what is going on which is important in code. Using the `case` and `when` allow me to easily add additional names to include. That *acts* like a chained "or" conditional test on an `if` statement, but without the additional noise.

[`each_with_object`](http://www.ruby-doc.org/core-2.2.0/Enumerator.html#method-i-each_with_object) is similar to [`inject`](http://www.ruby-doc.org/core-2.2.0/Enumerable.html#method-i-inject), except it is cleaner when we need to aggregate values into an Array, Hash or some object.

Summing the array is easy and there are many different ways to get there, but I'd use:

```
spent.map(&:to_i).inject(:+) # => 6900
```

Basically that converts the individual elements to integers and adds them together. (There's more to it but that's not important until farther up your learning curve.)

---

> I am just wondering if it is possible to replace the contents of the 'when' condition with an array of strings to iterate over rather than hard coded strings?

Here's a solution using an Array:

```
NAMES = %w[Dan Carlos]

spent = CSV.parse(data, headers: :first_row).each_with_object([]) do |row, ary| 
  case row['Name']
  when *NAMES
    ary << row['Total $ spent']
  end
end

spent
# => ["2548", "4352"]
```

If the list of names is large I think this solution will run slower than necessary. Arrays are great for storing data you're going to get to, as a queue, or for remembering their order like a stack, but they're bad when you have to walk it just to find something. Even a sorted Array and using a binary search is likely to be slower than using a Hash because of the extra steps involved in using them. Here's an alternate way of doing this, but using a Hash:

```
NAMES = %w[Dan Carlos].map{ |n| [n, true] }.to_h

spent = CSV.parse(data, headers: :first_row).each_with_object([]) do |row, ary| 
  case
  when NAMES[row['Name']]
    ary << row['Total $ spent']
  end
end

spent
# => ["2548", "4352"]
```

But that can be refactored to be more readable:

```
NAMES = %w[Dan Carlos].each_with_object({}) { |a, h| h[a] = true }
# => {"Dan"=>true, "Carlos"=>true}

spent = CSV.parse(data, headers: :first_row).each_with_object([]) do |row, ary| 
  ary << row['Total $ spent'] if NAMES[row['Name']]
end

spent
# => ["2548", "4352"]
```

Comment: @ theTinMan I am just wondering if it is possible to replace the contents of the 'when' condition with an array of strings to iterate over rather than hard coded strings?

Comment: Of course it is, but consider whether iterating over an array of strings is as fast as checking to see if there is a value in a hash. Arrays aren't meant to be searched, they're like storage containers to hold things you'll get to eventually, or need in a certain order. Hashes are great for rapidly retrieving something, such as "does this exist?" I'll add some code explaining what I mean.

Comment: Hey thanks I know what you mean. I used the includes? in the end and it worked a treat. Cheers

Comment: `includes?` is OK, but it can make your code run more slowly if the array being searched grows. It's just an intrinsic problem with searching unordered arrays. That's why using a hash is better, because it doesn't suffer from that problem.